# C# Добавление под-папки в планировщик заданий и создание в ней заданий

Tags: c#, task, scheduler

Как я могу использовать под-папку в планировщике заданий через C# чтобы создать там под-папку или добавить задание в эту под-папку если вам не трудно предоставьте примеры кода для C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Родного .NET API нет. Есть готовая обертка: https://github.com/dahall/TaskScheduler

Создание папки: вызов [`TaskFolder.CreateFolder`](https://dahall.github.io/TaskScheduler/html/M_Microsoft_Win32_TaskScheduler_TaskFolder_CreateFolder.htm) у `TaskService.Instance.RootFolder`.

Создание задания: [`TaskFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition`](https://dahall.github.io/TaskScheduler/html/M_Microsoft_Win32_TaskScheduler_TaskFolder_RegisterTaskDefinition.htm) у `TaskFolder`.